# Why I cannot update mysql database username and password?

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie in php language, I trying to do a simple login page , index page, and logout page, and now i trying to do change login password page, but it does not work in mysql , my coding have no any error but in mysql data it not change to what I updated in my update php form.

here is my code ,

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="paapuu_user"; // Mysql username
$password="mn78k1a2"; // Mysql password
$db_name="paapuu"; // Database name
$tbl_name="admin"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    //here the id that we post is the same id that we get from url
    //id indicates the id of this data which we are editing
    //id is unique and a particular id is associated with particular data   
    $id1 = $_POST['id'];    
    $username1=$_POST['username'];
    $password1=$_POST['password'];
    //updating the table
      $result=mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET username='$username1', password='$password1' WHERE id=$id1");
      echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
      $error1="<p>Update successfully!</p>";          
      echo "alert($error1); window.location ='viewpassword.php'";  
      echo "</script>"; 
}
```

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there though, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: This is not the right place to post this question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your actual form as well.

Are  you sure it takes you to inside of the `isset($_POST['update']);` ?
Also you could try

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE admin 
                       SET username='$username1', password='$password1' 
                       WHERE id=$id1") 
        or die(mysql_error());
```

To see if there's actually any problem with that query of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the variable $id1 with single quotes:

> $result = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET username='$username1',
>   password='$password1' WHERE id='$id1'");

It will prevent your query from having an error when no id is supplied, just like this:

> UPDATE admin SET username='$username1',
>   password='$password1' WHERE id=' ';

When no single quote is used, it will work this way:

> UPDATE admin SET username='$username1',
>   password='$password1' WHERE id=;

And I suggest you use your variable $tbl_name or just remove it from variable declarations if you won't use it in your queries. 
Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to put single quotes around WHERE id=$id1 for $id1

also if that does not fix the problem try replacing the single quotes on you variables to

something like'".$username1."'